# Need to pull 2 nodes and combine the information in LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, libxml2

I have an problem I could sure use some help with.  First, be gentle.  I am new to both perl and LibXML.

I have been parsing a document and placing elements into an array that is then written to a speadsheet column.  Durring testing it was discovered that some nodes have more than one child node of the same name.  I need to combine the text from each of these child nodes into one element of the array.

The (very simplified) format of the xml is:

```
<Group>
    <title>
    <description>
    <reference>
    <fixtext>
    <check>
        <check-content> "Some text I want to pull"
```

But occasionally it is like this:

```
<Group>
    <title>
    <description>
    <reference>
    <fixtext>
    <check>
        <check-content> "Some text I want to pull"
        <check-content> "Some more text I want to pull and join to the first"
```

I can pull all the text from "check-contents", but if there is more than one it throws off the row of data in the spreadsheet.  I need to be able to say something like:

If there are 2 or more "check-content" join the data an push into the array.  If not, just push the data into the array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I have been doing is this.

```
my @Check_Content;
my $Check_Content;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new() or die $!;
my $doc1 = $parser->parse_file($filename1);
my $xc1 = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($doc1->documentElement() );
$xc1->registerNs(x => 'http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1');

for my $Check_Content ($xc1->findnodes('//x:Group/x:Rule/x:check/x:check-content')) { 
     push (@Check_Content, $Check_Content->to_literal);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to process each `check` element and generate `check-content` string for it:

```
for my $Check ( $xc1->findnodes('//x:Group/x:Rule/x:check') ) { 

     my $result_string;

     for my $Check_Content ( $Check->findnodes('./x:check-content') ) { 
         $result_string .= $Check_Content->to_literal;
     }

     push (@Check_Content, $result_string);
 }
```

Comment: Or simply: `push(@Check_Content, join('', $Check->findvalues('x:check-content')));`

Comment: This is not working. It pulls everything under Group/x:Rule/x:check, but then it doesn't seem to parse $Check. Check_Content is always empty.                                                              for my $Check ( $xc1->findnodes('//x:Group/x:Rule/x:check') ) { 

    my $result_string;

    for $Check_Content ( $Check->findvalue('x:check-content') ) { 

        print "This is check contents\n\n$Check_Content\n";
         
        $result_string .= $Check_Content;
        push (@Check_Content, $result_string);
    }

 }